# Implementing a try/catch block in php constructor function

Tags: php, laravel-4, try-catch

I have a query with try-catch block. I am going to create object and if it fails it will throw error message or say redirect on some other page.

**Code**

```
function __construct() {
        try{ 
            $this->ServiceObj = AnyClass::getService('XXX');
          }
        catch{
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    } 

public function MyOwnFunction() {

    $getValueofCode = $this->_ServiceObj->set($endPoint_Url); //it's only example method not want to set anything
 }
```

Is this correct way to define and use the try catch block in a constructor? Can I use try & catch block in construction? If **NO** than is there a better way to achieve this?

***Thanks in Advance!!!***

Comment: Sure you can. However you might want to handle errors more globally: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors

Comment: @lukasgeiter , thanks  , but i want to know that can i redirect  as well?  actually i am using APis and if anyone can directly hit the result page i need to redirect him to main page where he needs to login using google.

Comment: Ahhh now I get it... I'll write an answer in a minute

Comment: @lukasgeiter..waiting for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use try catch in a constructor, just don't forget to specify the exception class you want to catch like `catch (\Exception $e)`. However Laravel will not process the returned redirect. (By definition constructors shouldn't even return something)

An easy fix for this would be calling `send()` on the redirect. This will return it immediately to the client and stop the app.

```
try{ 
    $this->ServiceObj = AnyClass::getService('XXX');
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    Redirect::to('/')->send();
}
```

But since you mentioned a login page, you might be better of using a [before filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) to check and redirect. Like the built in `auth` filter does.

A third solution would be [`App::error`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors). In `app/start/global.php` you could do something like this:

```
App::error(function(FooBarException $exception)
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Of course this only works if your exception is specific enough (replace `FooBarException` with the exception you want to catch)